# Is there a way of mixing boxplots for different subgroups from the same dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have this dataframe

```
A <- c(100,101,102,98,97,93,96)
B <- c("John","Anne","John", "Anne","John","Anne","John")
C <- c("cheap", "cheap", "expensive", "cheap", "expensive", "cheap", "expensive")
D <- c("USA", "Mexico", "Mexico","USA", "Mexico","USA", "Mexico")

dataframe <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)

   A    B         C      D
1 100 John     cheap    USA
2 101 Anne     cheap Mexico
3 102 John expensive Mexico
4  98 Anne     cheap    USA
5  97 John expensive Mexico
6  93 Anne     cheap    USA
7  96 John expensive Mexico
```

Imagine that I want to create on the same plot, different boxplots, **grouping B, C and D columns**.

So a **total of 6 boxplots (John, Anne, cheap, expensive, USA and Mexico)**.
**Taking into account the the group A values**, of course.

The problem here is that **each subgroup have a different total of samples to plot**, which makes me very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a matter of [reshaping the data to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format). Then it becomes a standard boxplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

dataframe %>%
  pivot_longer(-A) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, A)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how can I arrange the order of these grouped variables in the plot?

Comment: @JoãoMachado You can corece to factor and reorder the factor levels. Right after `pivot_longer`, include `mutate(value = factor(value, levels = c("John", "Anne", "cheap", "expensive", "USA", "Mexico")))`.